# Firebase Authentication allows any user to gain access when just one user logs in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

SO here is the story. I am working on a nodejs/express project with Firebase. This comes with a login system for users can view specific pages. Right now we are using Firebase for authentication and database. Node/express for the backend of the server. Html, css, bootstrap and angular js on some of the pages.

I installed Firebase for node via npm. This means there is NO Firebase front end code, Firebase is all on the back end.

when a user logins in, it sends the data from the html form via POST to login page on node such as

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next)
```

in this function we do the validation on the email and password and then call

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function()
```

So we have the Firebase authenticate in the backend, via express. we have NO Firebase on the front end, just to clarify.

we also have it in the back end since we can check if the currentUser() is authenticated or not so we can redirect users who try to access pages that is not theres.

**Problem**

when i pushed it to my google cloud server, I tested the page. It did not see me logged in and took me to the login page. at that point i was able to access my site. the problem was when my other partner on this project went to the site on her laptop from home, it did not ask her to login, but instead opened the homepage as if I was the one who logged in. basically it keep me logged in and anyone can see the page by going to it and not being asked to authenticate.

I am not sure what this is happening my theories are this.

1) I made mistake not related to Firebase

2) I have to deal with creating my own sessions or cookies in node for this

3) I have to make Firebase all front end and NOT backend to get all this to work

If anyone else needs more code, or more explanation please let me know. Thank you

Comment: You are signing in on the backend, this will persist the session for everyone. You have to sign in on the client side using the client SDK.

Comment: @bojeil ya that was bad mistake, i see that now, i went a head and moved it to front end and using backend to keep track of the token to check which users can access which page